# require is not defined

Tags: reactjs, requirejs

Im building a new React app but get the following error - 
"require is not defined"

hello-world.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="hello-world.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

hello-world.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Im running this from my client and don't have any web server running.

I tried to include http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js
but it gives a totally different error.

Answer (score 66):

You're trying to use a CommonJS module from within your browser.
This will **not** work.

How are you using them?
When you write `import ... from ...` in ES6 Babel will transpile these calls to a module definition called CommonJS and since CommonJS isn't around in the browser you'll get an undefined error from `require()`.

Furthermore, you're also trying to load RequireJS which uses a different module definition pattern called AMD, Asynchronous Module Definition, and will not take care of the `require` calls for you. You can [wrap them](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) in RequireJS specific calls.

If you want to use CommonJS modules in your code base you need to first bundle them with either [Browserify](http://browserify.org) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). The two tools will transform your `require` calls to some glue magic that you can use within the browser.

But in your specific case, if you remove the `import` calls and just let the browser take care of and attach the classes you've created to the `window` object your code should work.

Answer (score 6):

Also, note that when you are using submodules from React without another transpiler you will have to reference the top-level modules. I just know that in some cases there are people who will not wish refactor their projects and alter directories to handle webpack/browserify module imports.

So instead of using the CommonJS `import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'` you can instead reference hooks with `React.useEffect()` , `React.useState()`.

Just another solution for those who don't want to deal with any refactoring.

Comment: This is a good short-term solution.  Though ideally, you don't want to be namespacing everything you use React for, it's the entire reason for the import function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a basic hello world example [on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)
The code samples on react website doesn't show the full html document. In summary use React.useEffect and React.useState.  Get rid of the import statement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:  
  React.useEffect(() => {    // Update the document title using the browser API    
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <Example />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this the case though? Why do the docs use the import statement for hooks/react itself etc...?

Comment: React.useEffect does not work, shows the message 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component'