# require is not defined error with Babel file watcher in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm, babeljs

I have been following this [guide](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/) to transpile ES6 code into ES5 code in PhpStorm.

My problem is that when the script has an import statement:

```
import TestingView from 'component/TestingView';
class ItemPage extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <TestingView>
    }
}
```

TestingView.js

```
export default class TestingView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>Hello!!!!</div>
    }
}
```

The file watcher transpile it into the form of:

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _TestingView = require('component/TestingView');

var _TestingView2 = _interopRequireDefault(_TestingView);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; } /**
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                * Created by laukaichung on 7/10/16.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                */

var ItemPage = function (_React$Component) {
    _inherits(ItemPage, _React$Component);

    function ItemPage() {
        _classCallCheck(this, ItemPage);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(ItemPage).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    _createClass(ItemPage, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {

            return React.createElement(_TestingView2.default, null);
        }
    }]);

    return ItemPage;
}(React.Component);
//# sourceMappingURL=item_page.js.map
```

Obviously the built script won't work on the client side because there is a required statement. It will throw me `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Is there any solution to compile it in a working script? I know of browserify but I can't find any info about how it can be integrated into the babel file watcher.

Watcher config:

```
Program : /home/something/node_modules/.bin/babel
Arguments :$FileDir$ --source-maps --out-dir /something/js/build
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$
```

Answer (score 9):

Please see [require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698354/require-is-not-defined): you are compiling ES6 modules to CommonJS format, thus the issue. You need to either use Browserify or WebPack to bundle your modules, or compile to AMD format (`transform-es2015-modules-amd`) and include Require.js in yoiur application