# Use 3rd party components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react, and I feel like this should be obvious to me, but its not. How do I include a 3rd party react component so that I can call in inside my own components? For example I'd like to call this highlighter component (https://github.com/helior/react-highlighter) inside my render function. But I don't know how to actually include it.

I've tried adding 
`import {Highlight} from './react-highlighter/lib/highlighter.js';`
to the top of my components jsx file, but I get an error that require is not defined.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe you. If you're `import`ing it and not `require`ring it then you shouldn't be seeing that error at all.

Comment: You should be able to be able to import it by doing `import {Highlight} from 'react-highlighter'`. Did you actually install it?

Comment: I downloaded the files ... is there something more that is needed to install it?

Comment: Require is not built into browsers. you need to be using a package manager like webpack for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36698789/2733506

Comment: @Julie see the link John posted

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the react highlighter library (https://github.com/helior/react-highlighter), it shows:

`var Highlight = require('react-highlighter');`

Right now you are doing `import { Highlight }` which is **incorrect**.

This is the **correct** way, Note that this is the same as saying this in ES6:

`import Highlight from 'react-highlighter';`