# NodeJs : Require is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack, requirejs

I'm using **NodeJs** and **ReactJs**, with webpack config.

When I build my app, I have an error on navigator console :

> Require is not defined
>
> module.exports = require("jquery");

So I tried to import RequireJs, like this :

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({  
    nodeRequire: require,
}),

requirejs (['jquery'])
```

But I have the same error.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Is your webpack target web ? [ref](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target)

Comment: My webpack target node, as you can see in my anwer comment

Answer (score 0):

> You're trying to use a CommonJS module from within your browser. This will not work.

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698354/require-is-not-defined)

Try setting webpack target to web.

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = {

    target: 'node',
    //externals: [nodeExternals()],

    [...]
};
```

Comment: Based on your comment under your question, you posted this to answer the question that Gabriel asked about your question. When someone asks about your question, you have two options: edit the question, or respond in a comment. Responding a request for clarification about the question in an answer goes against the editorial rules of the site. We want answers to be solutions to the question asked in the posted questions. Please delete this and edit your question with the information.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.