# how to use require when using a library in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Install a library I do npm and everything is fine, it creates the folder in node_modules, but now I want to use it in a component but in the documentation require is used to call it, I do the same thing but in the console it shows me, **require is not defined**, how Can I solve this? I tried directly accessing the folder with but it doesn't work? how could i solve this?

Comment: `require` is used in commonjs mode (nodejs). For vue with webpack / vite, you must use `import xxx from 'my-library'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698354/require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I use import but it throws an error in bash about "emitter" =/

Comment: What is the library you are trying to use?

Comment: is html-pdf-node