# How do i deal with the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, vite

I have been struggling with publishing my website to github pages.After publishing, the page just shows a blank page with a dark color which is my websites background color.In the console there is the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". When in development on localhost everything works as expected.[Link to the website](https://21chozyn.github.io/MagnificentEvents/)
[Link to the repository](https://github.com/21chozyn/MagnificentEvents)

I read a question here and it encouraged not using commonjs ie "import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'" which i did but this did not change anything [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698354/require-is-not-defined)